# AWS Server 2012 R2, adding clients

Tags: windows, active-directory, amazon-web-services, domain-controller, internal-dns

I have a AWS machine running MS server 2012 R2. Setting up as a domain controller. I have both public and private IP address associated with the machine.

the internal network is on 172.xxx.xxx.xxx 
the public address is on 52.xxx.xxx.xxx

The DNS setting has been configured on the 172. network

My problem is i am trying to add machines to the domain will not join with this output of an error.

*The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
svr1.mycompany.com*

*However no domain controllers could be contacted.*

Any ideas ??

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-configuration-manage.html#configuration-instance

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the proper services in the domain controller is on, and run analyzer to ensure your DC is healthy
- Make sure your DNS is properly advertised
  [Best Practices Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759260.aspx)
  [Active Directory Best Practices Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378893.aspx)
- Test telnet port 389 and 3269 from this new machine to the DC